# Is $I(t)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (x-\pi/2)\exp\bigl(-t\sec(x)\bigr) dx$ continuous?

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity

> $$I(t)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(x-\pi/2)\exp\bigl(-t\sec(x)\bigr) dx$$ with $t>0$

The original problem that I had was much simpler, but I am curious about this function, is it continuous or not? I don't have any idea about how to demonstrate its continuity. Is it?

Comment: I saw your bio. Try English Language Learners Stack Exchange as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $I(t)$ is continuous.  To prove so, you can use the dominated convergence theorem and majorize the integrand by the constant function
$$
x \mapsto \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

In case you want to avoid the DCT, you can argue as follows:
let $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $t > 0$ be fixed.  We want to show that there is $\delta > 0$ so that if $|h| < \delta$, then $|I(t+h) - I(t)| < \varepsilon$.  To make $|I(t+h) - I(t)|$ small, we begin by writing
$$
\begin{split}
|I(t+h) - I(t)| 
&= \left| \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( x - \frac{\pi}{2} \right)\left[ \exp(-(t+h) \sec x )- \exp(-t \sec x) \right] \,dx \right| \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \pi} }\left| x - \frac{\pi}{2} \right| \left| \exp(-t \sec x)( \exp(-h \sec x) - 1) \right| \, dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \pi} }^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left| x - \frac{\pi}{2} \right| \cdot 1 \, dx  \\
&\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+  \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \pi} } \left | \exp(-h \sec x) - 1 \right| \, dx.
\end{split}
$$
Since the exponential function is Lipschitz on compact intervals, there exists $C$ so that $|\exp(u)-\exp(v)| \leq C|u-v|$ for any $u,v \in \left[- \sec(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \pi}), \sec(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \pi}) \right]$.  If we choose 
$$
\delta < \frac{2 \varepsilon}{\pi^2 C \sec\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{ \varepsilon}{\pi} \right)}
$$
and assume that $|h| < \delta$, then $|-h \sec x| < \frac{2 \varepsilon}{\pi^2 C}$, so
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \pi} } \left | \exp(-h \sec x) - 1 \right| \, dx \leq
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\varepsilon}{ \pi} } C \left( \frac{2 \varepsilon}{\pi^2 C} \right) \, dx \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{\pi},
$$
which means that
$$
|I(t+h)-I(t)| \leq \varepsilon.
$$

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity since you already received a good answer.*

We can have a quite good approximation of $I(t)$ using Taylor series built at $x=0$. This would give
$$e^t\,{e^{-t \sec (x)}}=1-\frac{t }{2}x^2+\frac{ t (3 t-5) }{24}x^4-\frac{t(15 t^2-75 t+61)}{720} 
   x^6+O\left(x^8\right)$$
Integrating the whole expression and using the bounds, this would give as an approximation
$$I(t)\sim\frac{\pi ^2 \,e^{-t}}{10321920}(15 \pi ^6 t^3-\left(672 \pi ^4+75 \pi ^6\right) t^2+\left(26880 \pi ^2+1120 \pi
   ^4+61 \pi ^6\right) t-1290240)$$ which is not "too" bad when compared with numerical integration.